# Asyncio in Flask-restful

Tags: flask, python-asyncio, flask-restful

I'm designing a web service using Flask-RESTful and one of the particular requirements that I have is that - once a POST method executes, it unblocks a GET method that is waiting on it.
So essentially:-

```
class MyService(Resource):
    def get(self, testCallId):
        app.logger.info("Received <%d>" %(testCallId))
        # need to block here waiting on post to complete...
        return "STATUS_UNBLOCKED"

    def post(self, testCallId):
        myData = request.get_data()
        app.logger.info("Received <%d>::<%s>" %(testCallId, mydata))
        # signal and unblock get method here...
        return "STATUS_OK"
```

I read about asyncio and have a decent grip of syncronization primitives like Event, Conditions etc. But if I wanted to achieve what I want to do above, how can I make get,post either event driven or lock/condition driven.

Comment: How is the POST triggered? Does `get` do that or is it from a separate request?

Comment: POST is from a separate request. This is a web service, so any client can post data to it

Comment: urlStr = 'http://localhost:1000/update/1234'
resp = requests.post(urlStr, "my posted data")

Comment: If any client can make the request, how does `get` know another request is coming?

Comment: In my code snippet above, "MyService" is a RESTful web service. It defines "get" and "post" methods that allows clients that want to talk to it through HTTP can either get data about it resource or modify(post) its resource. Scenario is something like this...client_1 calls "get" and MyService is blocked on returning from the method. It is unblocked when, lets say client_2 calls "post" and that triggers unblocking on the "get" method

Comment: @dirn, was that clarification helpful?

Comment: Not really. You've explained all of that already. My question is what happens when client_2 doesn't make a request? Is client_1 blocked indefinitely? What happens when client_1 connects to server_1 and client_2 connects to server_2? What happens when client_1 and client_2 call `get`, and then client_3 calls `post`? Regardless, this doesn't really seem like a use case for asyncio. The point of asyncio is to allow your code to yield control while it's performing traditionally blocking I/O. You're trying to introduce blocking, not remove it.

Comment: If client_2 does not make a "post", client_1 is blocked indefinitely. I think you are right, I'm trying to introduce blocking and it did strike me that ayncio is not what I want. I just implemented a threading.event.wait() so that get and post are synchronized. Thanks for the clarification!